# Table UI not set properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap table, table headers and table rows dynamically created using a javascript function. The issue is that the dynamically created rows looks very ugly:

[image]

```html
<div class="widget-content nopadding step1table">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive">
        <tr style="background-color:#002060" class="fontcolor">
            <th>
                <label for="No">#</label>
            </th>
            <th>
                <label for="">Book No</label>
            </th>
            <th>
                <label for="">Name</label>
            </th>
            <th>
                <label for="">ISBN</label>
            </th>
            <th>
                <label for="">Dept</label>
            </th>
            <th>
                <label for="">Price</label>
            </th>
            <th>
                <label for="">Action</label>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

```js
function drawRow(obj) {
    var row = $("<tr>")
    $(".bktbl").append(row);
    row.append($("<td><p>" + obj.Id + "&nbsp;&nbsp;</p></td>"));
    row.append($("<td><p>" + obj.bookno+ "&nbsp;&nbsp;</p></td>"));
    row.append($("<td><p>" + obj.isbn + "&nbsp;&nbsp;</p></td>"));
    row.append($("<td><p>" + obj.dept + "&nbsp;&nbsp;</p></td>"));
    row.append($("<td><p>" + obj.price + "&nbsp;&nbsp;</p></td>"));
    row.append($("<td class='imgclose'><p>" + '<img src="' + '/Content/Images/crossimg.png' + '"  width:"225px" height:"225px" />' + "</p></td>"));
}
```

All the dynamically created rows are compacted together. How can I solve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel you have to append the row after all tds are appended to row and you have to use a proper selector which is `$(".step1table table tbody")`:

```
function drawRow(JobjectArray) {

    var row = $("<tr>")

    row.append($("<td><p>" + obj.Id + "&nbsp;&nbsp;</p></td>"));
    row.append($("<td><p>" + obj.bookno+ "&nbsp;&nbsp;</p></td>"));
    row.append($("<td><p>" + obj.isbn + "&nbsp;&nbsp;</p></td>"));
    row.append($("<td><p>" + obj.dept + "&nbsp;&nbsp;</p></td>"));
    row.append($("<td><p>" + obj.price + "&nbsp;&nbsp;</p></td>"));
    row.append($("<td class='imgclose'><p>" + '<img src="' + '/Content/Images/crossimg.png' + '"  width:"225px" height:"225px" />' + "</p></td>"));

    $(".step1table table tbody").append(row);  // <-----should be placed here.

}
```

***`step1table` is the div element which holds your `table` HTMLElement.***

Answer (score 1):

Firstly the parameter your provide to the function is called `JobjectArray`, yet you're trying to retrieve the properties from `obj`. Secondly, the `table` element doesn't have the `step1table` class on it - you need to add it. Also you're appending multiple string literals together which is redundant. Try this:

```
function drawRow(obj) { // note the amended parameter name
    var $row = $("<tr>")
    $(".step1table").append(row);
    $row.append($("<td><p>" + obj.Id + "&nbsp;&nbsp;</p></td>"));
    $row.append($("<td><p>" + obj.bookno+ "&nbsp;&nbsp;</p></td>"));
    $row.append($("<td><p>" + obj.isbn + "&nbsp;&nbsp;</p></td>"));
    $row.append($("<td><p>" + obj.dept + "&nbsp;&nbsp;</p></td>"));
    $row.append($("<td><p>" + obj.price + "&nbsp;&nbsp;</p></td>"));
    $row.append($('<td class="imgclose"><p><img src="/Content/Images/crossimg.png" width:"225px" height:"225px" /></p></td>'));
}
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/byr55zuu/)